# What are exactly $request->attributes?

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

I´m very new to **php** and I don´t quite understand how the attributes are saved in `$request`.

We´re working with a class Controller.php, which contains every function that transfer the data to the html.twig; a class Model.php, which contains every functions with the queries to get the data from the database; and we work with Twig templates for the html part.

I know, that if I want to get the attributes of `'user'` I have to write:

`$request->attributes->get('user')`, because in there there is an array `'user'` with the parameters `'username'`, `'password'` etc.

But how does this attribute `'user'` (or whatever parameter) get to be in `$request`? I need to access to more data through the attributes, but first I have to know how they are saved there.

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Symfony are you using?  I'm guessing this is a legacy app?  Out of the box, controllers would use $this->getUser() to get the current user.  $request->attributes will not have any user information.  So I suspect your legacy app has a kernel listener which adding some some user information to your request attributes.  So poke around for custom event listeners.

Answer (score 12):

`attribues` is the only parameter bag of the Symfony Request object that's populated by the application. All the other parameter bags, like `request`, `query`, `server`, are populated with the http request data.

`attributes` can be populated at any point of the application lifecycle, but most of the time it will be done in a `kernel.request` event listener. [Docs explain more about event listeners](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html) and [built in Symfony Kernel events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html) in case you haven't used them yet.

The idea behind the `kernel.request` event is that it's called before the controller. It's perfect for implementing code that's suppose to be called for all your requests. For example, this is the way the built in `RouterListener` adds route path parameters as request attributes. So if the path is `/foo/{bar}` you're able to  access path placeholders with `$request->attributes->get('bar')`. [What happens in the `RouteListener`](https://github.com/symfony/http-kernel/blob/master/EventListener/RouterListener.php#L123-L125) is:

```php
// $parameters contains route path placeholders
$request->attributes->add($parameters);
unset($parameters['_route'], $parameters['_controller']);
$request->attributes->set('_route_params', $parameters);
```

If you'd like to add more attributes to your request you'll need to implement your own event listener. Once you register it, Symfony will call it automatically and your attributes will be populated.

Answer (score 0):

The request object contains data from a few different places. Some of it comes from front-end forms, the framework also loads the data for the currently logged in user and other server side variables that might be useful.

To add something new do this:
`$request->attributes->set('attribute', 'value');`

Comment: Misleading and inaccurate.  Out of the box the request object will not have any user information in it.

Answer (score 0):

I use that property of the request object to include objects or parameters that will be needed later. For instance, you can put extra información on the controller function that receives the request and then use that información on services that render content, or in events or whatever.

You set that information at the controller action, that is the one that has complete information about the kid of request, and the you can use that information to adapt the behaviour of a general service to that particular case use thanks to the received information.

You have more info here [Symfony Http foundation doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#component-foundation-attributes)